Relativistic time transformation in a rotating reference frame
I'm working to better understand Lorentz transformations, and it was suggested that a good exercise would be to derive the relativistically correct transformation laws from a stationary reference frame to one rotating around the $z$-axis. This seems like a useful way to grasp how relativity works in different reference frames.
Considering the stationary coordinate system $(t, x, y, z)$ and the rotating system $(t', x', y', z')$ rotating around the z-axis, it seems to me that the spatial coordinate transformation is simply the classical one, since the velocity of the rotating frame is always perpendicular to the $x'$ and $y'$ axes:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = x' \cos(\Omega t) - y' \sin(\Omega t) \\
y = x' \sin(\Omega t) + y' \cos(\Omega t) \\
z = z'
\end{cases}
$$
However, I am uncertain about the transformation of the time coordinate, which I assume takes the form $t = f(t', x', y')$. My initial thought was that the tangential velocity at a point $P = (x, y)$ is $v = \Omega \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and therefore, in a locally centered reference frame at that point, the time should transform as:
$$
ct' = \gamma (ct - \beta x)
$$
with $\beta = v/c = 0$, which simplifies to:
$$
t' = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1 - v^2 / c^2}}=\frac{t}{ \sqrt {1 - \frac {\Omega^2 (x^2+y^2)}  {c^2} }.   }
$$
That said, I'm uncertain about this reasoning, and it might be flawed. As someone pointed out in the comments, there should indeed be a distance beyond which the tangential speed exceeds the speed of light.

One problem with your proposal is that the tangential velocity can be greater than c. In the frame co-rotating with earth, everything beyond Pluto's orbit (roughly) has a tangential velocity greater than c. This causes the Lorentz factor to become imaginary.
This is just one of many indications that something odd is happening. You are definitely going to learn something interesting about relativity by going through this exercise, but it's going to be something more than just understanding the Lorentz transformation better.

you are right, I edited the last paragraph of the question to take in account you comment

You may want to look into Born rigidity for general rigid motion in relativity, and in the case of rotating frames Born coordinates.

I think it would be best to first to try to understand / distinguish the difference between general coordinates systems (or general reference frames) and observers reference frames defined on your spacetimes manifold $M$. The former being simply charts $\phi: U \subset M \to \mathbb{R}^4$ and the latter pertaining to a "smooth" set of frames along one fixed timelike curve $\gamma: I \to M$. [2]
To this end try reading Special Relativity in General Reference Frames by Éric Gourgoulhon, specifically chapters 3 Observers, 13.3.1. Uniformly rotating observers (your specific question) and 13.3.2 corotating observers (where things then get more difficult)
[2]: I remark this, since in general coordinate transforms one does not have to change the time coordinate, whereas when one compares two observers, one corotating (i.e. the worldliness revolves around one another) to the other one, with some fixed radius $r$ and $\Omega$, what interests us is the difference in their proper time so the analysis will be different (here see 13.3.2 from the cited source). If the two observers share their worldlines, and the frame of one is simply rotating, then more or less nothing surprising happens, as in your case (see 13.3.1).
